# Hiding TabHost from another Activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am developing an app where I need to hide the TabHost.The reason I need to remove it is that when you open the keyboard, it "sits" on the top of the keyboard.I have managed to access the TabHost using this code:

```
TabSample activity = (TabSample) this.getParent();
    final TabHost tabhost = activity.getTabHost();
```

The problem is that when I try to hide it using:

```
tabhost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

It also makes the current Activity invisible so you have to type blind. I need to find a way to make the TabHost invisible without making the current Activity invisible, or make the the be "behind" the keyboard.

The TabHost is stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
<activity android:name=".YourClass" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"></activity>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Is the TabHost located in top or bottom of your activity?

Comment: Yes, and it uses weight in xml to "hold it down".

Comment: That is strange. The above code works for me. Which activity are you specifying `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` for?

Comment: Should I specify it in my Tab class or in my child Activity class?

Comment: You specify it for the Activity who's holding the TabHost.